# Simple Android SUM & Multiplication Application crashing on AVD

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I have created one simple application using Android but this application crashes when I click on any of the View.Can you please help on below code of MainActivity.java:

```
public class CalculatorMainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{
int a3 =0, a1=0,a2 =0;
 Button b1,b2;
  EditText t1,t2;
 TextView v1;
 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_calculator_main);

     b1=(Button) findViewById(R.id.mul);
     b2=(Button) findViewById(R.id.sum);
     t1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
     t2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
     v1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text1);

     b1.setOnClickListener(this);
     b2.setOnClickListener(this);
     t1.setOnClickListener(this);
     t2.setOnClickListener(this);
     v1.setOnClickListener(this);
```

}

```
 @Override
 public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_calculator_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    String s1 = t1.getText().toString();

    a1 = Integer.parseInt(s1);

    String s2 = t2.getText().toString();
    a2 = Integer.parseInt(s2);

    if (v == b1)
    a3 = a1 + a2;
    v1.setText(a3.toString());  
    if (v == b2)
    a3 = a1 * a2; 
    v1.setText(a3.toString());

}
 }
```

It would be very helpful if you can give some solution to this Error.

Comment: Post a logcat of your crash and your `R.layout.activity_calculator_main`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It crashes here :

```
v1.setText(a3.toString());
```

because you don't have {} around your if action, and a3 is not defined.

Comment: a3 is defined as a primitive int...."int a3 =0, a1=0,a2 =0;
" this shouldn't even compile

Comment: ok, didn't see that. then probably a parsing error

Answer (score 1):

There are several issues here.

1) nitpick maybe but a cleaner way to handle button clicks is to define the andriod:onClick property of the views in XML and set it equal to a method name with signature public void myClickHandler(View v).  In that method, you can choose action based on view but you CANNOT use == on the views to do that.  Instead you need to compare the view ID's like this

```
if(v.getId() == v1.getId())
```

2)  As njzk2 points out, be careful about using (or not using) {} on your if blocks.  Right now you are only conditionally performing the line right after the if statement.  This is probably not what you want.

3)  Please PLEASE validate the input, this code is very fragile right now (you are trying to parse a string to an int without any check or error handling.  This is bound to break quickly.

4)  You do not want to call toString() on an Integer object let alone an int primitive.  As I mentioned in my comment this shouldn't even compile because it doesn't make sense - you can't call ANY instance method on a primitive.  Instead do v1.setText(new String(a3))  or v1.setText(a3 + "")

Answer (score 0):

I would also suggest reading up on converting numbers to strings.
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/converting.html